# Cannot install Android studio preview native support Mac m1

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, apple-m1

I saw on [this post](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-studio-canary-initial-apple-m1-macs/) on XDA that android studio preview support natively the ARM architecture for m1 Macs. On the screenshot we can clearly see that it's running on apple architecture but when i install the preview on my computer it's still running on intel architecture. How can i install the apple version of android studio ? Thank you

[image: My version of android studio]
[image: Still running on intel architecture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually need to download the version from the android studio archives from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)